# A weird form of Anacrusis

Tags: rhythm, anacrusis

I saw this in a piece the other day and was wondering if there is a term for it. The piece begins on a trill that ends on the first beat of a a measure. The rhytm then mimics a upbeat yet there is actually none.

I'm wondering if this is a typical Spanish rhythms or something common to the Romantic era.

For reference here is the sheets.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. "The rhytm then mimics a upbeat yet there is actually none." -> the four sixteenth notes which start the main motive (b-e'-g'-b') seem an upbeat to me, otherwise I don't see any mimicking.

Comment: Those four semis are the anacrucis. The first three and a half bars seem like an intro. It appears that it could be a march (lots are in 2/4), so the anacrusis gets the marchers ready on time. The pattern is repeated every 2 or 4 bars then.

Comment: I don't see anything unusual.  Heck, the last movement of Shostakovich's 5th (I think) begins with a full measure trill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are apparently confusing the notational peculiarity of an anacrusis right at the beginning of a piece (which is notated using a partial bar, usually without a bar number of its own) with the musical function of the anacrusis, a short leading phrase before its principal reference point, usually the beginning of a bar.

By far most anacruses don't interrupt an ongoing rhythm, the only slight exception being if they immediately follow a fermata.  Even then it is unusual to not make the bar have its nominal length.  Where that would not leave any room for the anacrusis, it's more common to add a full additional bar (starting with rests) rather than put down a double thin bar after the fermata and let the anacrusis start in a shortened bar right behind that.